# Crystal report resets my custom base class to ReportClass after every report change in designer

Tags: crystal-reports

As you know, **ReportClass** is the base class for all crystal report classes. I have some reports and in order to implement polymorphism I decided to have  **custom base report class** that is drived from **ReportClass**. so that other reports inherit from **MyCustomBaseReport** class. The problem is, whenever I change those reports in designer and save them, **ReportClass** automatically is replaced with **My Custom Base Report**.

Is there any setting that I could made to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Where did you construct your class in CR itself?

Comment: yes. My custom base class is a simple crystal report class that inherits from report class and other drived report classesinhertis from my custom base class.